# store checkbox value in locally and get back again

Tags: ios, objective-c

hello i have questions list which user can give answer only  in YES or NO so i have custom checkBox with image checkbox_fill and empty checkbox  .when some one select YES ,No will be empty Checkbox and if select NO ,YES will be empty and No will be Fill. now problem is i want to store locally this selected button if YES or NO.and get back if user move from one screen to another.my code is as below to select YES or NO.

```
- (IBAction)btnCheckBoxfor1:(id)sender {
    UIImage *selected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_fill.png"];
    UIImage *notSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"];

    if ([sender tag]==1) { // checkbox yes
        if (![sender isSelected]) {
            [sender setSelected:YES];
            [self.btnNO setSelected:NO];
            [self.btnNO setImage:notSelected forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self.btnYES setImage:selected forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }else{ // checkbox no
        if (![sender isSelected]) {
            [sender setSelected:YES];
            [self.btnYES setSelected:NO];
            [self.btnYES setImage:notSelected forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self.btnNO setImage:selected forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use NSUserDefaults to store value locally . Please check below -

```
 - (IBAction)btnCheckBoxfor1:(id)sender {

        UIImage *selected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_fill.png"];
        UIImage *notSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"];


        if ([sender tag]==1) { // checkbox yes

            if (![sender isSelected]) {
                [sender setSelected:YES];
                [self.btnNO setSelected:NO];
                [self.btnNO setImage:notSelected forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [self.btnYES setImage:selected forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                NSUserDefaults *boolUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                [boolUserDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"CheckBox"];
                [boolUserDefaults synchronize];

            }

        }else{ // checkbox no
            if (![sender isSelected]) {
                [sender setSelected:YES];
                [self.btnYES setSelected:NO];
                [self.btnYES setImage:notSelected forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [self.btnNO setImage:selected forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                NSUserDefaults *boolUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                [boolUserDefaults setBool:NO forKey:@"CheckBox"];
                [boolUserDefaults synchronize];


            }
        }
```

To get the value of check -

```
BOOL isCheck =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"CheckBox"];
```

Hope this will help you.

**Update**

Call below method on ViewWillAppear -

```
- (void)setvalueCheckBox {

    BOOL isCheck =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"CheckBox"];

    UIImage *selected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_fill.png"];
    UIImage *notSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"];


    if (isCheck) { // checkbox yes


            [sender setSelected:YES];
            [self.btnNO setSelected:NO];
            [self.btnNO setImage:notSelected forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self.btnYES setImage:selected forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            NSUserDefaults *boolUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [boolUserDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"CheckBox"];
            [boolUserDefaults synchronize];



    }
    else{ // checkbox no

            [sender setSelected:YES];
            [self.btnYES setSelected:NO];
            [self.btnYES setImage:notSelected forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self.btnNO setImage:selected forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            NSUserDefaults *boolUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [boolUserDefaults setBool:NO forKey:@"CheckBox"];
            [boolUserDefaults synchronize];



    }
}
```

Comment: how to set it again if selected YES or No?if user move to next screen and back in previous screen?

Comment: it  is stored but  Where is sender in -(void) setvalueCheckBox? i removed it but default it set YES as selected.if i remove [sender setSelected:YES];
            [self.btnNO setSelected:NO];

Comment: why do you need sender in -(void) setvalueCheckBox . Its a different method . If you want default as Selected Then  NSUserDefaults *boolUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [boolUserDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"CheckBox"];
            [boolUserDefaults synchronize]; at Appdelete